# Find the volume under the surface with several constraints

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume under the surface
$$z = a^2 - x^2$$
on domain restricted by these surfaces and planes:
$$y = 2x$$
$$x+y=a$$
$$z = 0$$
$$y=0$$

I made a drawing but I cannot even infer what the bounds of integration are.
When I drew all these lines (assuming $a=2$) I got this:
[image]

What are the bounds of integration in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To find the limit we need to make a sketch of the surface and bounds in the planes $z-x$ and $y-x$.

[image]

From here it follows that the volume is given by the sum of the following integrals

$$\int_{-a}^{0}\,dx\int_{0}^{-x+a} (a^2-x^2) \,dy $$

$$\int_{0}^{a/3}\,dx\int_{2x}^{-x+a} (a^2-x^2) \,dy $$

$$\int_{a/3}^{a}\,dx\int_{-x+a}^{2x} (a^2-x^2) \,dy $$

Comment: Why does the second triangular region not count here?

Comment: @Aemilius Yes of course, good observation! we need two more integrals of course! I have updated accordingly.

Comment: I will update the image later!

Comment: The problem is that the correct answer is $41/162$ and so the leftmost part is not included

Comment: Then there should be also the limit x=0.

Comment: According to the given constraints also the leftmost integral should be included.

Answer (score 1):

The integration will have to be done in two parts. As can be seen from the graph (**Desmos representation**:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mktcqyonrj) a triangular region is formed between **y=0, y=2x and y=a-x**. Hence the integrals obtained would be:
$$\int_0^{a/3} \int_0^{2x} \int_0^{a^2-x^2}  \,dz,dy,dx$$

$$\int_{a/3}^a \int_0^{a-x} \int_0^{a^2-x^2}  \,dz,dy,dx$$

The sum of these integrals should give you the total volume.

[image: a better graph]

In the graph, if you can imagine it, CFH is the surface we are looking for. We need to calculate the volume beneath this surface and above z=0.

Comment: The other answer points to the second triangle. How to determine which one should be taken?

Comment: You've to take both. I'm not really sure about what you're asking though. Also if you feel this answer answered your question correctly, plz upvote. It makes it better for the community.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ij5cnuyean
You are only taking the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (a, 0), (a/3, 2a/3)$
And what about the triangle defined by $(a/3, 2/3a), (a, 0), (0, 2a)$?

Comment: @Aemilius Firstly I didn't get why you plotted **x=a** and **x=-a**. In this graph [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ij5cnuyean) the triangle enclosed is pretty clear. We have to consider two separate triangles only because the lines change. **x=a/3** divides these triangles into 2. The two integrals I have obtained are for these two triangles.

Comment: The integration by dz is meaningless for the calcolation of the volume.

Comment: I plotted $x = a$ and $x = -a$ because 
$a^2 - x^2$ is supposed to be greater than zero, and so it must also be bounded by $x = a$ and $x= -a$

Comment: @gimusi I have done the integration by dz just following the convention of how volume is usually calculated using triple integrals. It's might seem superfluous here but helps to get in the habit.

Comment: @Aemilius Oh okay. That's fine. I hope you realize that graphing a function and its domain on the same graph isn't exactly correct. But its fine as long as you're aware of that. Cheers

Comment: @IshanRai Ah ok, it seems a bit strange but of course it is correct and why did you exclude the integral from $-a$ to $0$?

Comment: @gimusi check out the edit. I've attached another graph. Maybe that makes it clear what exactly I'm doing. If you still feel, questions welcome. Cheers.

Comment: @IshanRai Thanks it’s very nice and clear but why are you neglecting the integral from $-a$ to $0$ (that is my first integral).

Comment: @gimusi I don't get why you would do that. Isn't my domain bounded by the triangle DGC(refer the edit image)? So to find the volume restricted by the domain, I wouldn't consider that.